# 5*5 grid, in every 3*3 square of the grid must be 4 "lights"

Tags: python, algorithm, cycle, combinatorics

I'm very sorry I'm asking this question, but my coding skills are not so great, so I can not solve this problem: **there is a grid 5*5**, and a task is to find **minimal number of "lights"**, or "1" settled in a special way: **in every 3*3 square** of the big square, there must be **exactly 4** "lights". Counting with a pen, I've got this minimal number equals 7 (the answer is right). So my solution looks like this:

```
#creates a list
grid = []

#creates lines
for row in range(5):
    grid.append([])
    #creates columns
    for column in range(5):
        grid[row].append(0)

#one "light" must be in a center
grid[2][2] = 1

#this array counts all "lights" and will notice when there are 4 of them
light_number = []

def counter():
for row in range(0, 3):
    for column in range(0, 3):
        if grid[row][column] == 1:
           light_number.append(1)
print(len(light_number))
```

As expected, `counter()` works only for the first little 3*3 square. Wanting to have only one function for searching "lights" and not 9, I`ve tried to write something like this:

```
def counter():

#initial range of the counter
row_min = 0
row_max = 3
column_min = 0
column_max = 3

for i in range(9):
    for row in range(row_min, row_max):
        for column in range(column_min, column_max):
            if grid[row][column] == 1:
                #write it in a list
                light_number.append(1)
            column_min += 1
            column_max += 1
        row_min += 1
        row_max += 1
    #print a number of total lights
    print(len(light_number))
```

But it doesn't work, saying that grid[row][column] == 1 is **out of range**.

So, the problem is:

1. I can't write working counter, which should automatically see all little squares 3*3
2. I don't know, how to write all combinations of "lights".

Please, if you have ANY idea, tell me. If you think there can be another solution, please, say also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give any example of list and what you need to get output. may you can how the 5*5 grip looks and what you want to get from it. will be useful in solving

Comment: you need to re-set column_min/max for each row, as on second row you're asking for square 1-3 4-6 which obviously is out of range

Comment: Any way you look at it, your indexes are wrong.  If you want to iterate over three columns, or three rows, then you should be starting at index "0" and ending after index "2".  If you want to iterate over five columns/rows, then your last index should be "4".

Comment: Just a question:do you mean exactly 4 or at least 4 ones in every sub-square?

Comment: @Gregor, exactly 4, not more.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that exactly 4 is possible, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was about learning something about programming. As far as I can see, a simple backtrack-mechanism should be used:

```
import numpy as np

#initialize the grid with the middle set to one
grid = np.zeros((5,5))
grid[2,2] = 1
```

First, we need a simple check function, that returns `True` if the global grid is 
gracefully filled with ones:

```
# a method to check all sub squares starting at row and column 0 through 2
def checkgrid():
    # row 0 through 2
    for r in xrange(3):
        # column 0 through 2
        for c in xrange(3):
            # sum up all entries of grid matrix
            if grid[r:r+3, c:c+3].sum() != 4:
                return False
    return True
```

And here we go with the main method. The idea is the following: Every grid entry has a
unique identifier between zero and 24, its "idx". The aim is to find a valid configuration
where the six ones are spread correctly over the 24 grid entries (25 - middle entry).
All possible `binom(24, 6)=134596` solutions are enumerated through a simple loop and a recursive call to place the remaining entries, until the check-method returns `True` the first time, i.e. when a valid configuration is found.

```
# method that is recursively applied to set the next one
def recursive_trial(first, depth, maxdepth):
    # all ones are placed: check the grid
    if depth == maxdepth:
        return checkgrid()
    # enumerate possible grid positions as idx == 5 * r + c
    for idx in xrange(first, 25 - (maxdepth - depth + 1)):
        # get row and column idx
        r = idx / 5
        c = idx % 5
        # skip the middle
        if grid[r,c] == 1:
            continue
        # set entry to one
        grid[r,c] = 1
        # call method recursively to place missing ones until 7 in the remainder of the array
        if recursive_trial(idx + 1, depth + 1, maxdepth):
            return True
        # set entry back to zero
        grid[r,c] = 0
    # at this point, we failed with the current configuration.
    return False
```

A call to

```
recursive_trial(0, 0, 6)
print grid
```

yields (in a matter of milliseconds)

```
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Until someone comes up with a smarter algorithm, I can offer you a brute-force solution to enumerate all grids.

Represent each row of a grid as a "binary" number from 0 (all lights in a row are off) to 31 (all lights are on). Then, a grid will be a 5-tuple of such numbers. There are 32^5 = 33554432 grids - something that is possible to brute-force within minutes, if done efficiently.

To check a number of lights (bits) in a 3x3 square that starts at row `r` and column `c` (where `r` and `c` are between 0 and 2), use bit shifts and masks:

```
s = (nbits[7 & (g[r + 0] >> (2 - c))]
    +nbits[7 & (g[r + 1] >> (2 - c))]
    +nbits[7 & (g[r + 2] >> (2 - c))])
```

where `g` is a grid and `nbits` holds the number of bits for each number from 0 to 7. If some `s` != 4, the grid is not valid, go on to the next one.

Putting it all together:

```
import itertools

        # 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
nbits = [ 0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3 ]

def check(g):
    for r in range(3):
        for c in range(3):
            s = (nbits[7 & (g[r + 0] >> (2 - c))]
                +nbits[7 & (g[r + 1] >> (2 - c))]
                +nbits[7 & (g[r + 2] >> (2 - c))])
            if s != 4:
                return False
    return True

for g in itertools.product(range(32), repeat=5):
    if check(g):
        print g
        for row in g:
            print '{:05b}'.format(row)
        print
```

Comment: You could use `itertools.combinations` to iterate through the possibilities from most to least sparse, resulting in under a million checked. The optimizations beyond that probably are not worth it.

Comment: For the record: per the question author, the middle square obviously should be taken, dropping the possibilities to under 200,000. Then use the dihedral symmetry of order 8 to prune most of the remaining possibilities.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: since this (admittedly, naive) code completes in about 2 minutes on my machine, I haven't looked for anything more optimized. Still, if you have time, consider posting your solution to everyone's benefit.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I will solve it:

> ```
> grid = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
> grid33total = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
> for i in range(3):
>     for j in range(3):
>         grid33total[i][j] = sum(sum(x[0+i:3+i]) for x in grid[0+j:3+j])
> total = sum(sum(x) for x in grid33total)
> ```

The array grid33total contains the number of "lights" for each of the 3x3 squares.

Answer (score 0):

So, thankfully to efforts and help, I've came up with a solution.

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint
import sys


def check(grid):
    count = 0
    for row in range(3):
        for column in range(3):
            s = 0
            for right in range(3):
                for down in range(3):
                    if grid[row+right][column+down] == 1:
                        s += 1
                        if s == 4:
                            count += 1
    if count != 9:
        return False
    else:
        return True


for n in range(4, 25):
    for comb in itertools.combinations(range(25), n):
        grid  = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
        for index in comb:
            row = index // 5
            column = index % 5
            grid[row][column] = 1
            if check(grid):
                print(n)
                pprint(grid)
                sys.exit()
```

I've decided to use `itertools.combinations`.

```
row = index // 5
column = index % 5
grid[row][column] = 1
```

is a very interesting way to determine whether there must be "1" or "0". Program looks at the result of integer division (//), and that will be a row number, and then at the residual (%), that will be a column number. Then it places "1" here.

I know, it's not so beautiful and short, as nbits solution, but it's also a possible variant. On my computer it works just about five minutes.